# Virtual DJ 8 running in linux Ubuntu under Wine the music speeds up on its own

Tags: 18.04, wine

I am running [Virtual DJ 8](https://www.virtualdj.com/products/virtualdj/index.html) on Ubuntu and for some reason any music I play starts speeding up on its own.

It's running on a MacBook Pro 13-inch with Intel hardware. I am not sure how to fix this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?